# Can barcode Misread code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, barcode, barcode-scanner

in my asp.net mvc application on Register Form when users are using barcode scanner to insert data to textbox ,they say that it misses some portion of code like if they  scan 02501603566 they get 0250160**25**66 or 01301103564 can be 0130**14**03564 after register.can barcode misread some data? i tested on my barcode and everything works fine.customers have big amount of data so they cant check every time what they have scanned in input.this can happen 1 times in 100..

Comment: In most barcode format there is a checksum which prevents this errors. A mis-scan can always happen, you could prevent is by enabling the checksum-verification on the scanners

Comment: please ask them to scan the barcode using a different scanner is it possible that barcode scanner is not configured properly. secondly, check your label printing code is there any mistake in passing wrong data to the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its not only possible that a scanner misreads are barcode,  it definitely happens. 1D barcodes are the worst, but also cheap readers and readers configured improperly for the type of barcode being read can also be a problem.

- If you are in control of the code, use a barcode with the appropriate error checking (and there are many).
- Also check your barcode reader settings (they all have them).
- If all else fails check the barcode with a different scanner or barcode reader app and check if its the fault tolerance of the scanner itself.

> Misreads in the form of a perfectly scanning but wrong barcode can be
>   caused by scanner number substitution

Somehow the printed barcode image is wrongly  decoded by the scanner. A poor quality printed barcode can contribute to this, but barcode structure also contributes. UPC is notoriously vulnerable to number  substitution of 1 and 7, and 2 and 8 characters

> Low ISO Decodability scores can contribute to barcode misreads,
>   especially when they are caused by pixel rounding in the print process

This is most common in a thermal or thermal transfer printing but it can also occur in ink jet, DOD and other digital printing systems

> Scanners can also misread otherwise acceptable barcodes. Most often
>   the cause can be traced to damaged or dirty optics, but faulty decode
>   algorithms area known cause, albeit a rare one

Older, high-mileage scanners such as lasers tend to be more prone to misreads than newer, more sophisticated digital area imager scanners.

If a calibrated, ISO compliant verifier decodes and assigns an acceptable grade to a misreading barcode, one can be confident the cause lies with the scanner      and not the barcode itself. This is yet another example of how a scanner cannot effectively serve as a verifier

Comment: They will get new barcode scanner.hope problem will be gone